# IE7 with rowspan when dynamically collapsing multiple rows (extra space at bottom)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table, row, hide

I'm trying to dynamically hide/unhide multiple table rows using Javascript to mimic collapse/expand. here are relevant code snippets:

```
function selectionFilter(check, filter){
        var elem = document.getElementById('myScrollTable').rows;
        for(i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
            var type = elem[i].getAttribute('type');
            if(type== filter){
                if(check == true){
                    elem[i].style.display='';
                }else{
                    elem[i].style.display='none';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the sample HTML:

```
    <input type="checkbox" checked="true" value="t1" onclick="selectionFilter(this.checked, this.value);">some type 1</input >
<input type="checkbox" value="t2" onclick="selectionFilter(this.checked, this.value);">some type 2</input ><br><br>
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="" id="myScrollTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data1</th>
            <th>Data2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr type="t1">
            <td rowspan="50"><a href="something1">something1</a></td><td><a href="something2">something2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr type="t1">
            <td><a href="something2">something2</a></td>
        </tr>
            .
            .
        <tr type="t2" style="display:none;">
            <td rowspan="50"><a href="something1">something1</a></td><td><a href="something2">something2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr type="t2" style="display:none;">
            <td><a href="something2">something2</a></td>
        </tr>
            .
            .
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In Firefox everything is fine. However in IE, after the first time any row is hidden, when it is unhidden it has some extra space appending at the bottom. This does not happen when rowspan is not used. I tried many things but couldn't get rid of the extra space.

I would truly appreciate if anyone could give me some hint.

Comment: Probably not relevant, but in that HTML sample, you appear to be missing an opening `<tr>` tag, near `type="t2"`.

Comment: thanks for informing, that is true. I wrote the example on the fly, it might not really be a working version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using **block** instead of an empty string?

you should try using

```
elem[i].style.display = 'block';
```

and if this fails you should try

```
elem[i].style.display = 'table-row';
```

and allways you should check the w3schools documentation, its really usefull
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

tellme if this works for you

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I tried those option but I had no luck unfortunately. beside I made some minor changed to the provided html code (moved rowspan="50" from <a> tag to <td>, my bad)